# Reliable Client-Server architecture, switch to publish-subscribe?

Tags: client-server, zeromq, publish-subscribe

I need a reliable Request-Response model. I am using ZeroMQ. So far I am using `REQ/REP` pattern (and additionally `PUB/SUB`, but does not matter really now).

If the client crashes, it can restart and connect easily. I used therefore the "[Lazy Pirate Pattern](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all)" example from [ZeroMQ Guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all).
If the server crashes, things are not so easy. I have to tell my client that it has to restart for connecting. Of course, with additional channel like `PUB/SUB` I could handle that but what I ask myself is:

Isn't it easier to implement a PUB/SUB pattern for each direction which imitates a `REQ/REP` pattern? If the server crashes, it can easily connect without letting the client restart.

So the server has a `SUB` and a `PUB` socket, and the client has a `SUB` and a `PUB` socket.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *Isn't it easier to implement a **`PUB/SUB`** pattern for each direction which imitates a **`REQ/REP`** pattern?*

---

### ANSWER :

This question is undecidable.

---

### REASON :

Given zero MCVE-code-specificity, no one can formulate a metric for what is hard and what is easier.

As the root-problem, the multi-party distributed-Finite-State-Automaton, may have been specified in a **M**inimum-**V**iable-**P**roduct fashion. The **MVP**'s MUST-HAVE feature-set then explicitly dictates both the scope-of-implementation and also the minimum level of robustness any such MVP-implementation must be equipped with.

**`REQ/REP`**-distributed-behavioural-archetype has many different, native, properties, that a `PUB/SUB`-substitute will be hard to mimick/emulate. `PUB`-sender will be hard to enforce to deliver a Fair-Queue (Round-Robin) Load-balancing on the exgress-traffic direction, to name some example of issues, that will appear in case of an attempt to "just" replace one archetype with another.

Anyway, any wish to have some new sort of archetype for a distributed behavioural pattern over a multi-party network of agents, requires first a rock-solid specification of such a behaviour, before deciding on any potential ways of how to implement it with a use of some rudimentary tools.

Using a Maslow's hammer is out of question among the bad ideas inside the pool of bad and worst approaches.

---

### EPILOGUE :

If interested in the art of Zen-of-Zero, feel free to read [other **ZeroMQ** posts here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D%20is%3Aanswer) or Pieter HINTJENS' fabulous book "Code Connected, Vol. I" - a must read piece on this.